# Difference between SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateChainFile?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

Normally with a virtual host an ssl is setup with the following directives:

```
Listen 443 

SSLCertificateFile /home/web/certs/domain1.public.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/web/certs/domain1.private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/web/certs/domain1.intermediate.crt
```

**From:** [For enabling SSL for a single domain on a server with muliple vhosts, will this configuration work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/379544/for-enabling-ssl-for-a-single-domain-on-a-server-with-muliple-vhosts-will-this)

What is the difference between `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateChainFile` ? The client has purchased a CA key from GoDaddy. It looks like GoDaddy only provides a `SSLCertificateFile` (.crt file), and a SSLCertificateKeyFile (.key file) and not at `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

Will my ssl still work without a `SSLCertificateChainFile` path specified ?

Also, is there a canonical path where these files should be placed?

Comment: The most commonly places I see people putting the cert files is in `/etc/ssl`, `/usr/local/etc/ssl`, or in a `ssl` subdirectory specific to the website (eg `/home/www/example.com/data` has the website then `home/www/example.com/ssl` has the certs).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you don't ever need the chain for SSL to function.

What you always ***need*** is an `SSLCertificateFile` with a `SSLCertificateKeyFile` containing the correct key for that certificate.

The trouble is, that if all you give Apache is the certificate, then all it has to give to connecting clients is the certificate - which doesn't tell the whole story about that SSL cert.  It's saying, "I'm signed by someone, but I'm not going to tell you about them".

This usually works fine, as most client systems have a large store of CA certificates (both root and intermediate) which it can check through for a matching signing relationship to establish trust.  However, sometimes this doesn't work; most often the issue you'll run into is a client that doesn't hold the cert for an intermediate CA that's signed your certificate.

That's where the chain comes in; it lets Apache show the client exactly what the trust relationship looks like, which can help a client fill in the blanks between your cert, a root they trust, and the intermediate that they don't know about.  The chain can be included in your configuration in one of two ways:

- Embedded in the same file as you've set for your `SSLCertificateFile`, on new lines after the server certificate in order (the root should be at the bottom).  If you set it up like this, you'll want `SSLCertificateChainFile` pointed to the exact same file as `SSLCertificateFile`.
- In a separate file configured in the `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive; the CA certificate that issued the server's certificate should be first in the file, followed by any others up the the root.

Check the certificate file that you have now - I'm betting that it doesn't have the chain data included.  Which usually works fine, but will eventually cause an issue with some browser or other.

Comment: I think "usually works fine" doesn't really apply anymore to GoDaddy certs, if the intermediate isn't included.  I'm not even sure if it applies anymore to guys like Verisign and Thawte, actually, since they've moved to make the site certs more distant from the base ones that are included in the browser.  I imagine it makes revocation easier, since it's simpler to kill the intermediates.

Comment: "Embedded in the SSLCertificateFile": I wished this worked, but it doesn't seem to, and isn't mentioned in the docs. Your chain has to be put in `SSLCertificateChainFile`.

Comment: @SteveKehlet You're right that it's not documented, but I've had it work successfully in the past - how did you format the all-in-one file?

Comment: @SteveKehlet Actually, you're right, I remembered wrong; the way I had it set up for a single file was to have both `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateChainFile` pointed to the same combined file, which works - edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Beautiful! It works! Thanks so much for figuring that out.

Comment: When I put (in this order) server, intermediate, ca into a single file, and point to it with both `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateChainFile` apache won't start and I get `[error] Init: Multiple RSA server certificates not allowed` in error.log. Can you be more explicit about the format of this combined file that works for both? I tried adding / removing the private key, no dice.

Comment: @chmac That would probably indicate that you've either got extra SSL directives or extra vhosts with different certs configured (and no SNI support in your Apache).  Opening a new question and including your full configuration is probably your best bet.

Comment: For what its worth, I just recently found Chrome had no issues with a cert purchased from NameCheap, but curl and wget complained until I added their provided .ca-bundle as a SSLCertificateChainFile

Answer (score 5):

Here is a pretty good explanation of the differences as well as the observable impacts between choosing one vs the other:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899983/difference-between-sslcacertificatefile-and-sslcertificatechainfile

Answer (score 4):

Actually, GoDaddy does give you a intermediate chain:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/5238

Here's some more discussion.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/868/what-is-an-intermediate-certificate

The email from GoDaddy telling you how to download your new certificate will also have information on the intermediate certificate file.  It's somewhere towards the bottom, perhaps after your eyes glaze over from the verbiage and upsell.

In terms of what will happen if you don't include the proper SSLCertificateChainFile directive: you will see a big red warning in your browser because your SSL site will not validate in browsers, as they can't follow the chain of certificates from your site's cert to one owned by a certificate authority the browser knows about.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add to the previous good answers about the SSLCertificateChainFile that the order of the certificates in that file is important too. OpenSSL-based clients will sort out the order themselves but gnutls based clients will fail on a chain with the incorrect order.

Test the ordering with gnutls-cli, like

```
gnutls-cli --x509cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -p https wwwsec.cs.uu.nl
```

where /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt is the location your distro puts the combined certificates.